# Does Grub have an OS or drivers of its own?

Tags: grub

I've been reading the [Grub intro](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub.html) from Dedoimedo and despite being an excellent guide it raised some more questions:

Does Grub rely on any OS in its implementation? I know it's possible to configure it to load Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, etc. So I'm guessing it doesn't rely on any kernel (even a special-made minimal Linux kernel) right?  In that case, how can it show a graphical interface, access whatever media to load the kernel, etc. all in "20-30 KB of binary"?

Update: one follow up question: what are all those vmlinuz files in the `/boot` dir? Are those in any way related to Grub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, Grub is standalone and implements all its own drivers. It does take rather more than “20-30 KB of binary” to do this though; my `/boot/grub/i386-pc` directory contains 2.4 MiB’s worth of modules (which is where all the Grub features are implemented).

The `vmlinuz` files in `/boot` are the various Linux kernels you have installed. Grub doesn’t need them, they’re what Grub loads to boot Linux (along with an initramfs).

Comment: Good to know. I'm curious what are the vmlinuz images in /boot? Added it as an "Update" question to the original question so feel free to edit the answer if you see fit :)

Comment: Really all drivers? I don't know much about Grub, but I've been writing a bootloader for an embedded device as fast and compact `uboot` replacement. Of course I had to write some drivers, but not all, as there was some bootROM code executed by the CPU first, doing things like initializing the memory where my bootloader lives. I can imagine that Grub also relies on those lowest-level drivers, implemented in the BIOS or UEFI or whatever may be up to date in today's PCs.

Comment: I meant in opposition to using Linux drivers (or something else). The Grub drivers do use the BIOS in some cases; for example [`biosdisk.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/disk/i386/pc/biosdisk.c) uses the BIOS to access disks, but there’s also [`pata.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/disk/pata.c) to directly access PATA disks (allowing Grub to access drives which the BIOS can’t — which was useful on many older systems).